# Website performance is too much low because of audio player - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Recently I have created audio player for my website and I have upload it to live website, but after that my website's performance became too much low, if you check my website's performance in `google pagespeed insights` it will return `error` because of audio player, but if i remove that audio player, then it shows my wbsite's performance. Why is that? Is there any method to improve perfromance? I am really really worried about this.

> My website link: https://ifislam.com
>   Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found many issues on your site which are making its performance down:

- Minimize redirects
- Serve scaled images
- Defer parsing of JavaScript
- Optimize images
- Leverage browser caching
- Add Expires headers
- Make fewer HTTP requests
- Use a Content Delivery Network (CDN)
- Reduce DNS lookups
- Minify JavaScript and CSS
- Use cookie-free domains

Comment: I didn't get 2 things, minimize redirects and leverage browser caching?

Comment: Check this article to understand more https://gtmetrix.com/minimize-redirects.html

Answer (score 1):

as i can see in google insights your website is not slow because of audio player but the wrong execution time of javascript(which affects on main thread execution) and heavy sizes of images.
what you can do is:

1. use lazy loading for images (lazy loading packages)
2. async loading of scripts (use `async` `defer` for js scripts)
3. try caching of resources for fast reload after first visit

Comment: how can i use `async defer` for js?

Comment: it depends how you are using script (js) in your project but for example if you are using `<script>` you can write `<script async defer src="yourScript.js">`
but i will suggest you to read about `async` and `defer`, so that you can decide which is best in your scenario.

Comment: also `leverage browser caching` is nothing but `caching` resources like images, js scripts etc. so that your application doesn't have to do tedious work of loading all the resources again and again and by doing that you can also minimize load from main thread which will lead to faster reloads

Comment: also you can try lazy laoding images as i saw it has 500kb size of file which will cause main thread load

Comment: I am doing these all, but still my performance is too much low,